# xslt xml to html: how to match something start with 'n' but not 'name'?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

This is a problem I came across.

source xml:

```
<n0>Hello1</n0>
<n1>Hello3</n1>
<name>Hello2</name>
```

I can use

```
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'n')]">
```

to match n0,n1. but I dont want to match 'name', what can I do to match only n0,n1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best match would depend on your rules.

For example if you just want to exclude 'name' specifically, then use...

```
*[starts-with(name(),'n')][not(self::name)]
```

On the other hand if you wanted to match 'n' followed by a digit (as opposed to n following by a letter or dash), then use...

```
*[starts-with(name(),'n')][number(substring(name(),2,1))>-1]
```

It is not possible to give an optimal solution, until you can unambiguously and rigorously define the desired matching condition.

Also, if it is **ONLY** n1 and n2 that you want to match, then you can use...

```
n1 | n2
```

Answer (score 0):

To match all elements named "n" followed by zero or more digits you could use

```
*[translate(name(), '0123456789', '') = 'n']
```

This removes all digits from the name and then checks that the only thing left is an "n". Since XML names cannot start with a digit, you don't need to check that the name starts with n specifically. To make sure you have one or more digits rather than zero or more, just add an extra check that `name() != 'n'` or `not(self::n)`.